# How does git create interactive menus?

Tags: git, powershell, interactive

For example:

[image]

I have git helper scripts for our local devs and I would like to create the same pretty command line interactive menus. How does git do it?

Comment: I’ve never seen this... what did you type to get this? Have you got a plug-in installed in your shell?

Comment: That is git on windows running in powershell.

Comment: whch command shows this? It looks like `git add -p` but options are different

Comment: also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script and IIRC cmd has some built-in for it

Comment: This is powershell, I do not have bash. I added the powershell tag to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-add--interactive.perl , search for `list_and_choose` function

Comment: Oh, this is perl. I need to figure out whether I can leverage this code from my powershell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a program like [`manifoldco/promptui`](https://github.com/manifoldco/promptui) (no setup required), which allows you to define your interactive steps:

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/6d98a9569064c2d13bbe1aee6b58b59e010f5ba0/68747470733a2f2f6d656469612e67697068792e636f6d2f6d656469612f78554e6461304e67623571736f674c7342692f67697068792e676966]

Comment: But it requires `go`, doesn't it?

Comment: @mark only to develop your shell. Once it is compiled, it requires nothing.